# Adding a custom claim to the onCreate user firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying on a firebase cloud function to add some custom claims when a new user is created. As the custom claims I need to add a User role to the created user

I have tried on some tutorials where user role is added after the user created. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wa3CMK4E2Y. But I thought of adding custom claims on the creation of the user and returning with the response

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addDefaultUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    let uid = user.uid;

    //add custom claims
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{
        isAdmin: true,

    });


});
```

Even the above code get executed in firebase, nothing happened and claims were not received in the response. Is it not a good practice to add custom claims on User creation? What will be the reason for not attaching the custom claims with the above code

Comment: What do you mean by "claims were not received in the response"?

Comment: Auth functions don't have a "response", nor do any background functions.  FYI your code right now makes all new accounts "admin" accounts.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: No actually. This code segment is only a demo code to get an idea. I need to add a default user role. Not an admin user role.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Cloud Function code looks OK and the Custom Claim shall be correctly set.

The problem you seem to encounter is that you cannot confirm that the claim is correctly set. As a matter of fact the `setCustomUserClaims()` method returns a non-null Promise containing void (and nothing else!).

You could do as follows if you want to verify, through the Log, that the claim has been correctly set.

```
exports.addDefaultUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    let uid = user.uid;

    //add custom claims
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{
        isAdmin: true
    })
    .then(() => {
         //Interesting to note: we need to re-fetch the userRecord, as the user variable **does not** hold the claim
         return admin.auth().getUser(uid);
    })
    .then(userRecord => {
        console.log(uid);
        console.log(userRecord.customClaims.isAdmin);
        return null;
    }); 
});
```

Finally, note that it is not at all a "bad practice" to add custom claims on User creation! It makes full sense to do that upon user creation when you know which Claim(s) to set.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have tried your code. But for console.log(user.customClaims.isAdmin); , I get an "undefined" in firebase function logs

Comment: Give me 15/20 minutes, to double check. For the answer I've adapted a code that does work for me. I'll double check it.

Comment: I've adapted my answer. You will see that we need to re-fetch the `userRecord` in order to get the correct Claim(s) (i.e. the ones that were just set). The initial `userRecord` passed to the handler function does not contain the Claim and is not updated. (In the code I've adapted for the answer, I trigger the Claims setting via a database trigger so I have to fetch the userRecord through this "extra" step)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Anyway your answer worked for my cloud function and it did print the admin value in logs. Even though when I try to fetch the claims from firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult() from client side it didn't get the custom claims inside the claims object. Only the default claims are there.

Comment: @user3581438 - you have to refresh the claims on the client ```getIdTokenResult(true)```

Comment: thank you I think you just fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.addDefaultUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    let uid = user.uid;

    //add custom claims
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{
        isAdmin: true
    })
    .then(() => {
         //Interesting to note: we need to re-fetch the userRecord, as the user variable **does not** hold the claim
         return admin.auth().getUser(uid);
    })
    .then(userRecord => {
        console.log(uid);
        console.log(userRecord.customClaims.isAdmin);
        return null;
```

Hope it works.

Comment: This is exactly @renaud-tarnec's answer.